# How can I add the Google App Engine dependencies to my gradle build without making a flat file repository?

Tags: google-app-engine, gradle

It is the first time i try to use gradle

I use the following build.gradle

```
buildscript {
   repositories {
      mavenCentral()
   }

   dependencies {
      classpath 'org.gradle.api.plugins:gradle-gae-plugin:0.7.6'
   }
}

apply plugin: 'gae'

dependencies {
    gaeSdk 'com.google.appengine:appengine-java-sdk:1.7.3'
}

gae {
   optimizeWar = true

   appcfg {
      email = 'myemail'
      passIn = true

      app {
         id = 'guestbook'
      }
   }
}
```

and I can do a `gradle gaeVersion` just fine

```
:gaeVersion
Release: 1.7.3
Timestamp: Wed Oct 24 03:01:39 CEST 2012
API versions: [1.0]

java.vm.vendor: Oracle Corporation
java.vm.version: 23.0-b21
java.version: 1.7.0_04
os.name: Windows 7
os.version: 6.1
```

but if I do a `gradle gaeRun`

it fails with a compile error for `HttpServlet` which I totally understand because I did not add the servlet dependencies.

**How do I add the GAE dependencies to my gradle config without making a flat file repository?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could retrieve the dependency from Maven Central as well. The configuration `providedCompile` is provided by the [War](http://gradle.org/docs/current/userguide/war_plugin.html) plugin which the GAE plugin applies automatically. In case you notice that you do need to provide the Servlet API library in your WAR file (e.g. if the GAE runtime environment requires you to add it) you need to use the configuration `compile` instead.

```
repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    providedCompile 'javax.servlet:servlet-api:2.5'
}
```

Comment: Thank you. It was just me not getting gradle correct ;-) btw. thanks for providing a GAE Gradle Plugin

Comment: For me it also need de appengine-api? Tried `providedCompile 'com.google.appengine:appengine-api:1.8.5'` but does not work?

Comment: ok this works :) `providedCompile 'com.google.appengine:appengine-api-1.0-sdk:1.8.5'`